# How to target CSS media query if both device resolution is similar but device screen size(in inches) is different?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

I have two different devices

1, T2 light -

- **LCD : 15,6“**
- Resolution : 1920 × 1080
- Device pixel ratio : 1.4375
- CSS media query target : width = 1336px

2, T2 mini -

- **LCD : 11,6“**
- Resolution : 1920 × 1080
- Device pixel ratio : 1.4375
- CSS media query target : width = 1336px

Only difference of both devices is screen size in inch.

I want to write different css media for both devices. Any idea, how can i target particular device ?

Thank You

Comment: Hi. Css is not aware of the display size, it cannot "see" the size of it. If the 11.6" is a touch device and the 15.6" is not, then you may detect with JavaScript the touch functionality and load the corresponding stylesheet.

Comment: The resolution is a representation of the Dots Per Inch (DPI). If the screen is wider physically, this but the DPI is the same, then the dots are simply bigger. No way to determine if the screen is physically bigger.

Comment: @bron Thanks for comment, both devices are touch screen so can't apply this solution.

Comment: @Twisty yes, it's true that DPI are same for both devices. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device sniffing is **always bad practice** but in your case you are **comparing only 2 particular devices**. By showing the user-agent string on both devices, you can look for differences between them in hardware or OS related words.

For example, a difference in the user-agent string could be: device 1 "galaxy" and devicve 2 "nokia". Use the difference in a `.match()` to select a style.

Better not compare the browser name (ex. Chrome), browser engine (ex. WebKit), brand name (ex. Apple), or version numbers.

A simple test case:

The JavaScript will add a classname to `<div class="page">`. With this classname you can use css to give all items in this div a certain style.

```js
let ua = navigator.userAgent;
document.querySelector(".ua").innerText = ua;

let page = document.querySelector(".page");

if (ua.match(/iphone/i)) {
    page.classList.add("iphone");
}
else if (ua.match(/android/i)) {
    page.classList.add("android");
}
else if (ua.match(/windows/i)) {
    page.classList.add("windows");
}
```

```css
.iphone  .ua { color: red; }
.android .ua { color: blue; }
.windows .ua { color: brown; }
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <p class="ua"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution will work for only different OS indetification

Comment: That is correct. It is not possible to detect the screen size in inches. Even by using a huge database with all User Agent strings it is *not* full-proof. On the other hand, detecting the screen size in pixels is not a problem at all.